# iOS Notification Extension to load media not called

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am running project in Xcode 12.2 and on iOS 14.2 to load images in a push notifications. I am getting the below error messages in console and the Push notification shows up without the image.

```
SpringBoard [com.mydomain.myapp] No extension available for bundle
SpringBoard [com.mydomain.myapp] Error was encountered trying to find service extension: error=Error Domain=UNErrorDomain Code 1904 "Unknown application"
```

mutable_content is set to 1 in payload. App Groups is enabled.
I tried rebooting the device and this also didn't worked.

Kindly let me know if there is a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> SpringBoard [com.mydomain.myapp] No extension available for bundle
> SpringBoard [com.mydomain.myapp] Error was encountered trying to find
> service extension: error=Error Domain=UNErrorDomain Code 1904 "Unknown
> application"

You need to *make sure your application deployment target and extension deployment target is the same.*

It works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Both my iOS and Notification extension are having deployment target 10.0. Still didn't work.

Comment: @Maddiee Could you share some code about showing the Image? I will check that.

Comment: It was a reference issue, the extension reference was missing in the main iOS project. That was causing the issue. Thanks for your support and for me it works in different deployment targets also. iOS 9.0 for iOS project and iOS 10.0 for extension

Comment: @Maddiee Okey, do you mean have solved it now?

Comment: @Maddiee Great! You also could update your solution in Answer. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.